# How to disable static content access from url?

Tags: spring-boot

I have:

1. "loginPage.html" file in "/resources/static/" directory of project
2. Controller with mapping "/login" which returns "loginPage.html" content

Now when I request `localhost:8080/loginPage.html`, server responses with content of "loginPage.html".

When I request `localhost:8080/login` I also get content of "loginPage.html", but now controller deal with this action.

I do not want to let user get login form via `localhost:8080/loginPage.html`. Only via `localhost:8080/login`.

Requesting `localhost:8080/loginPage.html` should cause 404 error message.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details of what you have tried.

Comment: I want to have an access to loginPage.html only via controller. Now I have via controller [link](localhost:8080/login) and via requesting static resource [link](localhost:8080/loginPage.html). Enough clearly?

Answer (score 1):

As per [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/804), if you want to disable serving of static resources, you need to set the following property to false in `application.propertiers`:

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: Now requesting "/loginPage.html" produces 404 as I expected, but requesting "/login", which uses loginPage.html resource, also produces 404.

Comment: Can you please detail what exactly are you trying to achieve. "/login" gets resolved to  "/loginPage.html". Are you trying to disable this for all static resources (not having ".html") in the url?

Comment: I have:
1. "loginPage.html" file in "/resources/static/" directory of project
2. Controller with mapping "/login" which returns "loginPage.html" content

 Now when I request "localhost:8080/loginPage.html", server responses with content of "loginPage.html". 
When I request "localhost:8080/login" I also get content of "loginPage.html", but now controller deal with this action. 
I do not want to let user get login form via "localhost:8080/loginPage.html". 
Only via "localhost:8080/login".